# Plotting a changing function on one graph

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I am implementing a machine learning algorithm that attempts to do a linear regression by implementing gradient descent. What I want to do is to plot the points, then plot the currently computed line; then, as the parameters change, I want the new function to then replace the old one, and so on until the iterations are done.
I define the x, and y arrays to fit the data:

```
x=np.array([170,187,166,157,157,166])
y=np.array([190,187,153,150,162,166])
```

(Oh, and I did `import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt)`
I then plot the points by:

```
plt.scatter(x,y)
```

When I have the current iteration of the regression line (the current slope(m) and y-int(b), I do this:

```
plt.plot(x, m*x+b)
```

It only plots the final version of the line rather than the intermediate lines. I want to make a kind of cool "animation" to show the computer "learning" the correct line. I would probably pause between each "guess," then erase the line and draw a new one.

I want to plot the line, erase that line, then plot a new line. Not sure how to implement that,

Comment: That sounds like the standard kind of animation you would find when typing in "matplotlib animation" in a search engine. Did I miss something? Is there an actual problem involved with this?

Comment: I thought my question was obvious. I amended it to see i that helped. I am a noob, so a simple Google does not help much.

Comment: Start with [this example](https://matplotlib.org/gallery/animation/simple_anim.html). Update your question with what you have tried and an actual problem.